# Browser Detection Python / mod_python?

Tags: python, http-headers, mod-python, browser-detection

I want to keep some statistics about users and locations in a database. For instance, I would like to store "Mozilla","Firefox","Safari","Chrome","IE", etc... as well as the versions, and possibly the operating system.

What I am trying to locate from Python is this string;

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.14) Gecko/2009090216 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.14

Is there an efficient way to use Python or mod_python to detect the http user agent/browser?

Answer (score 3):

`HTTP_USER_AGENT` contains this information, and will be passed in the environment variables your application uses.  In mod_python, this is expressed as:

```
def my_request_handler(req):
    req.add_common_vars()
    agent = req.subprocess_env.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT")

    # `agent` now contains the full user agent of the browser, or None
```

It's a basic CGI thing, but this is how mod_python gives it to you.

Answer (score 3):

The method suggested by Jed Smith works, but I was sure there was a simpler way.

The `req.headers_in` variable contains all the header info, and you can easily access the user agent using mod_python by calling:

```
req.headers_in[ 'User-Agent' ]
```

It is not necessary to call `req.add_common_vars()` when using this method.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the **Django**-Framework you get the user agent like this

```
request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

The very nice plugin **httpagentparser** extracts every detail and puts it a dictionary.

Installation works via pip

```
pip install httpagentparser
```

Hope this helps... I googled about 30 min until I found something useful :)

Ron