# How to open a new tab in same browser using robot frame work

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

As far as I know there is no straight keyword to open new tab in selenium2library. I have seen the below code which opens a new tab in IE(default browser)for the given URL

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

But I want to write a keyword which opens a new tab on current running browser (it may be any browser).

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689861/browser-detection-python-mod-python) question. Similarly use `HTTP_USER_AGENT` to return the browser name. Say it returns 'firefox', then pass it to `current_browser = webbrowser.get('firefox')` and `current_browser.open('http://www.google.com')` and this will automatically open up a new tab (if possible) in the open browser. Hope this helps. I'm not sure if it will work, which is why I do not post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can try

```
Execute Javascript    window.open('')
Get Window Titles
Select Window    title=undefined
Go To   ${URL}
```

This Code helps to Open New tab in the same browser and collect the Windows Title of all tabs in same browser. 
Based on the Window Title name , it identifies the Newly opened tab and launch the URL

Comment: This is a working answer. The `Execute Javascript    window.open('')` can be replaced with the new SeleniumLibrary keyword, `Press Keys      None      CTRL+T` to open the new tab in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Javascript Keyword

```
Execute Javascript   window.open('NewTabUrl');
```

Example:

```
Execute Javascript   window.open('https://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 2):

It's sloppy, but you can try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import  Keys 

actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
element.send_keys('t')
actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
```

I'm not aware of a browser-agnostic method.

After opening a new tab you can change tabs by finding the window handle with `driver.window_handles` and switching to the appropriate handle: `browser.switch_to_window(handle)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AutoIt Library For Simulating KeyStroke in Robot Frame Work

```
Import AutoItLibrary
Import Selinium2library

send  "^t"  Open the New Tab
```

same way simulate others

Ctrl+Tab – Switch to the next tab – in other words, the tab on the right. (Ctrl+Page Up also works, but not in Internet Explorer.)

Ctrl+Shift+Tab – Switch to the previous tab – in other words, the tab on the left. (Ctrl+Page Down also works, but not in Internet Explorer.)

Ctrl+W, Ctrl+F4 – Close the current tab.

Ctrl+Shift+T – Reopen the last closed tab