# How to open a new tab in a browser using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

How to open a new tab in a browser using robot framework

```
Open Browser    https://www.google.com/    chrome
Press Key    id=identifierId    \\20
Maximize Browser Window
```

my code trying to press Ctrl+T.
the test is passing but the new tab is not opening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open new tab in same browser using robot frame work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232137/how-to-open-new-tab-in-same-browser-using-robot-frame-work)

Comment: have a look: https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903